# Yii2 - Currency symbol position

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2 I'm using the function `Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($sellingPrice);` to print currencies. As the locale is Danish the output for this is something like

```
10,00 kr
```

Now I've been trying to use this same function to display

```
kr 10,00
```

but I cant find how to do this.

The [documentation's](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asCurrency()-detail) directions are to set those options through `$numberFormatterOptions` and `$numberFormatterTextOptions`, but no directions as to what exactly to set for those

I tried, among a thousand other things:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($modifier->getMoneyFormat('sellingPrice'), null, [NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION => NumberFormatter::PAD_BEFORE_PREFIX], [NumberFormatter::PADDING_POSITION => NumberFormatter::PAD_BEFORE_PREFIX])
```

but this won't work. I also tried passing  `[NumberFormatter::PAD_BEFORE_PREFIX => true]` to both `$numberFormatterOptions` and `$numberFormatterTextOptions` but both wont work.

What am I doing wrong? Or how should I achieve this?

Comment: What value does $sellingPrice variable contain?

Comment: a regular integer. And getMoneyFormat that is used in the example above returns a formatted string. You can assume here that I'm always using getMoneyFormat()

Comment: do you have the [PHP intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) loaded? those other params you're trying to pass won't take effect without it

Comment: yes I checked the local server using php - m and its loaded

Comment: Why do you want to have currency symbol before amount even if it is against your locale rules?

Comment: A stupid business requirement @rob006

Comment: If your business requirement is to have currency formatting inconsistent with current locale, then maybe you should not use `Yii::$app->formatter` directly - create custom component which will handle currency formatting without involving locale settings.

Comment: @rob006 you're probably right. At first I thought that formatter handled this though without workarounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change Language or 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code:**

**Example:** assuming `'numberFormatterSymbols'=>[\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL => 'kr'],`

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'en-US';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(1000); // output: kr1,000.

Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'ru-RU';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(1000); // output: 1 000 kr.
```

**also for**:

```
\Yii::$app->language = '';
```

**Or in the configuration file**

```
$config = [ // or  for locale
   'language' => 'ru_RU',  // Output: 1 000 kr
   'language' => 'en_US',  // Output: kr1,000
    //...
   'components' => [

      'formatter' => [
        'currencyCode' => 'RUB',
        'locale' => 'ru-RU',
        'numberFormatterSymbols'=>[\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL => 'kr'],
      ],

     //...
```

> The 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code indicating the default currency to use for asCurrency(). If not set, the currency code corresponding to $locale will be used. Note that in this case the $locale has to be specified with a country code, e.g. en-US otherwise it is not possible to determine the default currency.
>
> Note: The Formatter class is meant to be used for formatting values
>   for display to users in different languages and time zones.

Comment: This is a good and helpful answer. I upvoted it for this reason. This does not solve my problem unfortunately though. If I changed the locale to 'en-US' as suggested, the currency is displayed as DKK. What I give in currency symbols is ignored. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Actually forget my comment. This was because I had currency code set in config. When this was removed it worked. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: I **edited**  the code. The problem was with me (wrong typing).  I apologize . Regards and Thanks